# How to hook viewpager swipe event up to update state react-native android?

Tags: android, events, android-viewpager, react-native

My js is abit rusty and im abit confused about how to update the state after a swipe event in my react-native android app. Im trying to hookup this [ViewPager](https://github.com/zbtang/React-Native-ViewPager) based on the [official ViewPager](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/viewpagerandroid.html) and i just want to get the `pagenum` to update when the slider slides to that page. Any help on how?

The slider itself works, but im confused about how to update state based on events or callbacks. What i really wish to do is update the background color styling of the parent view after each page slide.

**Welcome Page**

```
import {IndicatorViewPager, PagerDotIndicator} from 'rn-viewpager';

var AboutPage1 = require('../about/AboutPage1');
var AboutPage2 = require('../about/AboutPage2');

class WelcomeScreen extends Component {

    state = {
        pagenum: 0
    };

  render() {
        <View >
            // the parent view i wish to change bgcolor
            <View style={{flex:1}}>
                // this is the viewpager
                <IndicatorViewPager
                        indicator={this._renderDotIndicator()}
                        onPageScroll={this.onPageScroll}
                        onPageSelected={this.onPageSelected}
                        onPageScrollStateChanged={this.onPageScrollStateChanged}
                        ref={viewPager => { this.viewPager = viewPager;
                }}>
                    // some components in this first view
                    <View onPress={this.onPageSelected.bind(this,this.pagenum)}>
                        // some components
                    </View>
      //  these are just views wrapping pages that are themselves views
                    <View onPress={this.onPageSelected.bind(this,this.pagenum)}>
                        <AboutPage1 onPress={this.onPageSelected.bind(this, this.pagenum)}/>
                        <Text>{'count' + this.state.pagenum}</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View>
                        <AboutPage2 onPress={this.onPageSelected.bind(this, this.pagenum)}/>
                        <Text>{'count' + this.state.pagenum}</Text>
                    </View>
                </IndicatorViewPager>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
}

    _renderDotIndicator() {
        return (
            <PagerDotIndicator
                pageCount={5}
            />
        );
    }


 // callback that is called when viewpager page is finished selection
 onPageSelected(e) {
     console.log('state is: '+this.state)
     this.SetState({pagenum: this.state.pagenum+1});
    console.log('state is: '+this.state)
 }

}
```

**About Page**

```
  <View>
        <Text>Welcome to My App</Text>
  </View>
```

**Error**
`error: 'undefined is not an object when evaluating this.state.pagecount`

Comment: I just noticed in the docs i overlooked `ViewPagerScrollState` which i might need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should bind this keyword.Like this:

```
 <IndicatorViewPager
                        indicator={this._renderDotIndicator()}
                        onPageScroll={this.onPageScroll.bind(this)}
                        onPageSelected={this.onPageSelected.bind(this)}
                        onPageScrollStateChanged={this.onPageScrollStateChanged.bind(this)}
                        ref={viewPager => { this.viewPager = viewPager;
                }}>
...

  </IndicatorViewPager>
```

Comment: I just installed rn-viewpager library and the `IndicatorViewPager` doesn't contain `onPageScroll`, `onPageSelected`, `onPageScrollStateChanged`. I didn't find any listener to know which page is currently displayed. I saw that only `ViewPager` component contain those props, but I need to use `PagerDotIndicator` which is not suitable with `ViewPager`. Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You might be mixing up two different plugins but using ViewPager from `'@react-native-community/viewpager'`, What you want to achieve can be done as follows (Notice the use of `onPageSelected` and the handler);

```
<ViewPager
     pageMargin={10}
     style={styles.viewPager}
     initialPage={currentPageIndex}
     onPageSelected={(eventDate) => this.handleHorizontalScroll(eventDate.nativeEvent)}
>
          {pages.map((item) => (
            <Card style={{ elevation: 3, margin: 50, borderRadius: 10, backgroundColor }}>
              <CardItem header style={{ borderRadius: 10, backgroundColor }} bordered>
                <Text>Card Header</Text>
              </CardItem>
              <CardItem style={{ flex: 1, borderBottomWidth: 0.2, backgroundColor }}>
                <ScrollView>
                  <Text style={{ fontFamily, color, fontSize, textAlign: 'justify' }}>
                    {item.text}
                  </Text>
                </ScrollView>
              </CardItem>
              <CardItem style={{ borderRadius: 10, backgroundColor }}>
                <Text>Card Footer</Text>
              </CardItem>
            </Card>
          ))}
</ViewPager>
```

Your horizontal Scroll handler or onPageSelectedHandler should then be something like this:

```
handleHorizontalScroll = ({ position }) => {
    console.log('Current Card Index', position);

    this.setState({currentIndex: position})
};
```